# Derivation of FFT from DFT

Tags: fft

Can someone please share a link or source where I can find the derivation of FFT(base-2) from the DFT. I need to put this in latex for my thesis and am finding so many different explanations that I don't know which one to use.

Comment: this belongs on math.stackexchange.com